# Pass variables to ember handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an Ember.js ArrayController and some handlebar code that looks like this

```
<p>{{length}} {{pluralize length "thing"}}</p>
```

Then I've got a handlebar helper that looks like

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('pluralize', function(count, str){
    debugger;
    return (count > 1 ? str+"s" : str);
  }
);
```

When the debugger breaks I observe seeing that `count = 'length'` not a number like I would expect.

So what gives? What's the correct way to accomplish my obvious task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/MwTuw/2/

The trick is to use `Ember.registerBoundHelper` which passes all the relevant data as a final argument to the function.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('pluralize', function (count) {
  var options = Array.prototype.pop.call(arguments);
  var string = options.data.properties[1];
  return (count > 1 ? string+"s" : string);
});
```

This removes the `{{if controller.length}}` hack that is required with the other solution and means that adding or removing additional objects will update the value accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('pluralize', function (property, options) {
  var count = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, property, options);
  var _options = options;
  count = parseInt(count, 10); //to be sure ...
  if (count > 1) {
    _options = _options.concat('s');
  }
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(_options);
});
```

**EDIT**

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/nwJAg/11/)

**EDIT 2**

Here is your working updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/MwTuw/1)

> Basically the problem was that the handlebar helper was acting when the controller still had no records, I've added a `if` helper to the template that listen on the `controller.length` and fires when it changes and so invoking also the handlebar helper to parse the value.

Hope it helps

Comment: Nope, count gets set to zero. I'm looking to use a property on the array controller (it's length).

Comment: can you show (more of) the template where the count values lives?

Comment: I've added a working fiddle, try to change the count on the ApplicationController to 1 for example to see the pluralization going away...

Comment: I'm using it in a a rails app, here is a js fiddle not working http://jsfiddle.net/MwTuw/

Answer (score 1):

Using **Ember.registerBoundHelper** will make all the key-value pairs in the template  available as an hash on the 2nd parameter of the helper:

*Handlebars template:*

```
{{orderShow dataOrderBy key1="value1" key2="value2" ... keyN="valueN"}}
```

*Javascript:*

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('orderShow', function(order, options) {
  if(options) {
    for(var prop in options.hash) {
            alert(prop + '="' + options.hash[prop] + '"')
    }
  }

  return order;
}
```

This behaviour is described at the end of the following page: http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html